# What are the components of a Xively HTTP PUT request to send to my SIM800 GPRS module?

Tags: gsm

I have an Elecrow GPRS shield which I want to use to post temperatures from 3 x DS18B20s to Xively. The example code is a mystery to me. You can find in full at this link: http://www.elecrow.com/wiki/index.php?title=GPRS/GSM_Shield_v1.0#A_Simple_Source_Code_Example

The relevant function is here:

```
///send2Pachube()///
///this function is to send the sensor data to the pachube, you can see the new value in the pachube after execute this function///
void Send2Pachube()
{
mySerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
delay(100);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CSTT=\"CMNET\"");//start task and setting the APN,
delay(1000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CIICR");//bring up wireless connection
delay(300);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CIFSR");//get local IP adress
delay(2000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CIPSPRT=0");
delay(3000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"tcp\",\"api.cosm.com\",\"8081\"");//start up the connection
delay(2000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CIPSEND");//begin send data to remote server
delay(4000);
ShowSerialData();
String humidity = "1031";//these 4 line code are imitate the real sensor data, because the demo did't add other sensor, so using 4 string variable to replace.
String moisture = "1242";//you can replace these four variable to the real sensor data in your project
String temperature = "30";//
String barometer = "60.56";//
mySerial.print("\"method\": \"put\",\"resource\": \"/feeds/43634/\",\"params\"");//here is the feed you apply from pachube
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print(": ,\"headers\": \"X-PachubeApiKey\":");//in here, you should replace your pachubeapikey
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print(" \"_cXwr5LE8qW4a296O-cDwOUvfddFer5pGmaRigPsiO0");//pachubeapikey
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print("jEB9OjK-W6vej56j9ItaSlIac-hgbQjxExuveD95yc8BttXc");//pachubeapikey
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print("Z7_seZqLVjeCOmNbEXUva45t6FL8AxOcuNSsQS\",\"body\":");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print(" \"version\": \"1.0.0\",\"datastreams\": ");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("[\"id\": \"01\",\"current_value\": \"" + barometer + "\",");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("\"id\": \"02\",\"current_value\": \"" + humidity + "\",");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("\"id\": \"03\",\"current_value\": \"" + moisture + "\",");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("\"id\": \"04\",\"current_value\": \"" + temperature + "\"],\"token\": \"lee\"");


delay(500);
ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println((char)26);//sending
delay(5000);//waitting for reply, important! the time is base on the condition of internet 
mySerial.println();

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");//close the connection
delay(100);
ShowSerialData();

}
void ShowSerialData()
{
while(mySerial.available()!=0)
Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

Note that although this is called "send2Pachube" it uses the Cosm API, which still works. 
The section following the line

```
mySerial.println("AT+CIPSEND");
```

is where the HTTP gets formulated. I've assembled the string in the example code and it looks odd. The API key goes on about four times longer than it should. I'm not sure what all those colons are doing in there, are they a String operator? Can anyone give me an example of an HTTP PUT request for Cosm or Xively that illustrates how this string should be assembled?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a working solution to this issue. Here's the values you can edit and the function:

```
String FEED = "YOUR_FEED";
String KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
String DATASTREAM1 = "YOUR_DATASTREAM1_NAME";
Int VALUE1 = YOUR_VALUE1;
String DATASTREAM2 = "YOUR_DATASTREAM2_NAME";
Int VALUE2 = YOUR_VALUE2;

void send2Cosm()
{
mySerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
delay(100);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("AT+CSTT=\"CMNET\"");//start task and setting the APN,
delay(1000);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("AT+CIICR");//bring up wireless connection
delay(300);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("AT+CIFSR");//get local IP adress
delay(2000);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("AT+CIPSPRT=0");
delay(3000);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"tcp\",\"api.cosm.com\",\"8081\"");//start up the connection
delay(2000);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("AT+CIPSEND");//begin send data to remote server
delay(4000);
ShowSerialData();

mySerial.print("{\"method\": \"put\",\"resource\": \"/feeds/" + FEED + "/\",\"params\"");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print(": {},\"headers\": {\"X-ApiKey\":");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print("\"" + KEY + "\"},\"body\":");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print(" {\"version\": \"1.0.0\",\"datastreams\":");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print("[{\"id\": \"" + DATASTREAM1 + "\",\"current_value\": \"");
mySerial.print(VALUE1);
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.print("\"},{\"id\": \"" + DATASTREAM2 + "\",\"current_value\": \"");
mySerial.print(VALUE2);
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
mySerial.println("\"}]}}");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println((char)26); //sending = ctrl+z
delay(5000);//waitting for reply, important! the time is base on the condition of internet 
mySerial.println();

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");//close the connection
delay(100);
ShowSerialData();

}


void ShowSerialData()
{
while(mySerial.available()!=0)
Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

To answer part of my question: no, the colons aren't a String operator, they're part of the HTML. Here's an example of the formed URL that gets sent:

```
{"method": "put","resource": "/feeds/YOUR_FEED/","params": {},"headers": {"X-ApiKey":"YOUR_API"},"body": {"version": "1.0.0","datastreams":[{"id": "DATASTREAM1","current_value": "VALUE1"},{"id": "DATASTREAM2","current_value": "VALUE2"}]}}
```

This code updates my feed but after several hours the updates stop. I'm still troubleshooting this new problem so I'm not 100% sure that this code is good. I will post back if the problem's in here.